# OpenCV - Lane detection 'numpy.ndarray' error

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to run a code on lane detection using opencv library in python. But I am getting a `numpy.ndarray` error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
 File "lane_detect.py", line 10, in <module>
    line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
from cv2 import * 
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = imread("Lane1.png", 0)
edges = Canny(img,100,200)
lines = HoughLinesP(edges,1,pi/180,100,minLineLength=100,maxLineGap=10)
for line in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = line[0]
    line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

'''for line in lines:
   for ex in line:
    print ex'''
imwrite('Lane1.png', img)
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
namedWindow("Canny", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
imshow("Canny", edges)
imshow("Image", img)
waitKey(0)
destroyAllWindows()
```

There might be other errors in the code.

Please suggest some changes in the code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)`?

Comment: You can refer to the openCV documentation if you want to understand houghlines. I am trying to  construct a houghline.

Comment: Are you able to recognize the lanes in your image??

Comment: Yeah. But due to lack of understanding of opencv in python, I coded the same in C++. After that the whole structure of the code has changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what is happening there. `lines` is the list of detected Hough Lines. You are not constructing them, but they are detected by the algorithm. I think in the loop you are trying to draw them onto the image, but a name collision happens here. the `line` variable from the for-loop overrides the `cv2.line` function which you probably want to use to draw the line. So either select a different variable name, or call `cv2.line` for drawing.

Comment: I see you have figured out the same solution as well :D

Comment: Perfect example of shooting oneself in the foot due to lazines (to type `cv2.`). :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 10th line in your code to:

```
cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
```

You want to draw the lines you have found using `HoughLinesP()`. Hence `cv2.line()` does it for you. You might have overlooked it while coding